# encryption and decryption using certificates in C#

Tags: c#, certificate, encryption-asymmetric

I have a big XML that needs to be encrypted on one server (by one c# application), and needs to be decrypted on another server (by another c# application). The XML contains the critical  information for which this encryption needs to be done.

My real need is that my server that does the encryption should **only** know the public key and the private key is known only to the server which is doing the decryption. Also, this private key should be stored in a safe area on the server such as certificates.

What should be the steps that can help me achieve so?

1. Can I generate my private key and store that in certificates or the certificates will generate the private key on their own?
2. Also, if certificates generate the public and private key, can the public key be separated from the certificate and exported to the server where the encryption has to be done?

Comment: There is in general no way to securely store a private key (or anything) on the server other than the server being secure. The main step on making the server secure is 2-factor authentication. But if it is on a shared computer beware of root escalation exploits by other users of the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How the key-pair and certificate are generated depends on the software used.
2. The private key can be obtained from a certificate.

The general method is to encrypt data with a symmetric encryption algorithm such as AES and encrypting the symmetric key with asymmetric encryption algorithm such as RSA or EC and the public key. This is done for two reasons: 1. Asymmetric encryption is very slow compared to symmetric encryption. 2. The data length for Asymmetric encryption is limited by the key size: a typical key size is 2048-bits and that limits the data length to 245-bytes.

There is in general no way to securely store a private key (or anything) on the server other than the server being secure short of the server having an HSM or access to a TPM. The main step on making the server secure is 2-factor authentication. But if it is on a shared computer beware of root escalation exploits by other users of the server.

HSM - [Hardware Encryption Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module)
TPM - [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)

Comment: What is root escalation exploits. If you could can you redirect to any good web resource?

Answer (score 3):

Asymmetric encryption is very processor intensive and, consequently very slow. For that reason, it is not normally used to encrypt large amounts of data.

What is normally done is symmetric encryption is used to encrypt the bulk of the data and asymmetric encryption (public key) is used to encrypt the keys used in the symmetric encryption.

The encrypted keys are transmitted with the encrypted data. The keys are decrypted (private key), then using the symmetric keys the bulk data is decrypted.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption also limits the data length to slightly less than the key size so with a 2048-bit key the data is limited to 245-bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Kevin and zaph. You mean I should use the same key (symmetric) for encrypting and decrypting my XML data and this key would have to be known to both of my servers, right? Also, the symmetric key that has encrypted the data would be further encrypted using the asymmetric key (public), and will be decrypted using the asymmetric key (private). So the question is, can I pre-generate these asymmetric public and private keys and store the private key in a certificate so as to prevent any security fallout?

Comment: The reason for using asymmetric encryption to encrypt the symmetric keys is specifically so that they do not need to be known by both servers. In fact they are usually generated at the time of encryption. You encrypt it on the encrypting server then transmit it with the encrypted data to the decrypting server.

Comment: The "secret" value for this scenario is the certificate private key used to decrypt the symmetric keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have achieved it. 
On my server 2, I am generating a certificate(.cer) and a private key(.pvk) using the 'makecert.exe' command. Then, using the 'pvk2pfx.exe',  I am generating a .pfx file. This is the file which will now house the certificate and private key.
Now I export the certificate with just the public key to the server 1, where I encrypt the data, and on Server 2 using the certificate's private key I decrypt the data.